# What eventListener Should I use here?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I am creating this compiler and my problem is that I need to detect the changes in the upper text box and I was able to detect all changes except the change when the user clicks the clear button and the text clears up in the box. Can anyone please suggest what js event listener I can use to detect this?

Comment: If you are about to run an function when detect a change event in the text box when the clear button is clicked, why don't you just call the function straight away when the clear button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple addEventlistener as follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">Hello</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " ";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here, the p tag earlier had a value but after the button is clicked the value into p tag is set to the value assigned in the js. So what you have to do is to make the value inside your text field to null by using the `.innerHTML=" "`

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` event will be helpful.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('clear_Code');
let textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
button.onclick = function() {
  textbox.innerText = '';
}
```